# ipython notebook matplotlib plot for dataframe throwing non gui exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

When I try to plot a dataframe in my notbook , I am seeing a 'non gui' exception being thrown.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys,os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=ts.index, columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()
plt.figure(); df.plot();  #<-- Exception here
```

There is a plot displayed , with the first column of `df` plotted and then I see this exception. When I try to plot a series , I dont see any issue.  Here is the exception trace :

(looks like we are trying to plot the df as an 'interactive' plot, is there any other function / parameter to try not 'interactive')

```
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in generate(self)
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in _make_plot(self)
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in _ts_plot(cls, ax, x, data, style, **kwds)
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\plotting.pyc in format_dateaxis(subplot, freq)
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kw)
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.pyc in draw_if_interactive()
     68         figManager =  Gcf.get_active()
     69         if figManager is not None:
---> 70             figManager.show()
     71 
     72 class Show(ShowBase):

...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.pyc in show(self)
   2618         optional warning.
   2619         """
-> 2620         raise NonGuiException()
   2621 
   2622     def destroy(self):

NonGuiException:
```

Comment: Your code works for me. This seems to be a configuration problem. Could you post details about your platform, the python interpreter you use, and the versions of the involved packages?

Answer (score 0):

### The Solution

I got the exact same error this morning when working in a similar environment (Anaconda, Python 2.7). The error message is almost identical to yours. Interestingly enough, the same code run without any error in a different environment, same machine. So that's the first hint that it could be be a package / dependency issue.

The solution that works is an update to the package that is referenced by the error message. Yours was:

```
...\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.pyc in show(self)
   2618         optional warning.
   2619         """
-> 2620         raise NonGuiException()
   2621 
   2622     def destroy(self):
```

So what you'd try is an update on your `matplotlib` package. Since you use `conda`, I'd recommend:

```
conda update matplotlib
```

### Confirm that Matplotlib is updated

You should confirm that `matplotlib` is updated. In your command prompt (terminal) you should see:

```
cairo:       1.14.12-hab642c4_1               --> 1.14.12-hc4e6be7_4    
...
matplotlib:  2.1.0-py36h5068139_0             --> 3.0.0-py36h54f8f79_0
```

Alternatively, in your Jupyter Notebook / iPython, run:

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.__version__ # print 3.0.0
```

Now proceed to plot again - tried your code in Python 2 and 3 and both works (again, using Anaconda).